# Explaining effect a method is having on an array

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, nsmutablearray

Am new to coding so apologies for dumb question.

I am following a Swift tutorial and have written the below code; creating a Class called Note, a method called dictionary and a class method called saveNotes.

I am confused by the last line: aDictionaries.addObject(allNotes[i].dictionary()

I understand that I am running a method on the aDictionaries array to add an object, passing in allNotes[i]. Can someone explain exactly what the .dictionary() function is doing here? Is it converting the array allNotes into a dictionary? Is it attaching a dictionary to the array allNotes? Presumably its not converting the array allNotes into a dictionary? That doesn't seem possible from whats inside func dictionary. Or maybe I'm wrong.

Any comment would be gratefully received.

```
var allNotes : NSMutableArray = [] 

class Note: NSObject {
var date : String
var note : String

override init(){
    date = NSDate().description
    note = ""
}

func dictionary() -> NSDictionary{
    return ["note":note, "date":date]
}

class func saveNotes(){

    var aDictionaries:NSMutableArray = []
    for var i:Int = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++ {
        aDictionaries.addObject(allNotes[i].dictionary())
    }
    aDictionaries.writeToFile(filePath(), atomically: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm still not clear on what exactly allNotes[i].dictionary() *is*! Is it an array or a dictionary? Is it an array with an extra dictionary element? Thanks.

Comment: 'allNotes[i].dictionary()` just executes the `dictionary()` method on one of the notes, which will return a dictionary that contains all the data in the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aNote.dictionary()` returns aNote date and text as one NSDictionary. You send this method to a single note, not to an array. The method return a single NSDictionary.

Your code is equivalent to the following

```
...
class func saveNotes(){
   var aDictionaries:NSMutableArray = []
   for var i:Int = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++ {
      let noteAtIndexI = allNotes[i]
      let dictionaryForNoteAtIndexI = noteAtIndexI.dictionary()
      aDictionaries.addObject(dictionaryForNoteAtIndexI)
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Although I'm still not clear on what exactly allNotes[i].dictionary() is! Is it an array or a dictionary? Is it an array with an extra dictionary element? Thanks.

Comment: It is a dictionary. allNotes[i].dictionary() is one dictionary containing the information related to the single note at index i

Answer (score 0):

```
   allNotes is an array of Note objects

    allNotes[i] gives you a single Note object  for index i

.dictionary() func returns NSDictionary of that Note Object:
```

like

```
{
 "note":"some Note",
 "date":"2015-07-22 09:51:35"
}
```